# Why do some Atlanteans need water breathing suits?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, aquaman

In the new *Aquaman* movie there are a number of scenes where Atlanteans are seen on land wearing suits filled with water so they can breathe​. In some of the fight sequences we even seen their suits breaking and the person inside "drowns" like a fish out of water.

Yet Aquaman, his mother, and numerous other Atlanteans have no trouble breathing both air and water. I suppose in Aquaman's case he was half Atlantean and half human, but that doesn't explain the others who had this ability.

I felt like this was either not explained at all or else I missed it. Why do only some Atlanteans need water breathing suits while others don't?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Mera at one point explains ___"... only the highborns can breath water as well as air."___ (I think it's when she and Arthur go to Atlantis for the first time and enter the shipwreck that has an airpocket inside it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It's class/genetically based.

Here's an excerpt from an article i found.

> While it involves genetics, it also seems to be a matter of class standing. Through the film's dialogue, it's explained only highborn Atlanteans are able to breathe both air and water. That means royalty and anyone who associates with them on a regular basis.
> <sub><sup>*- [Aquaman Movie Explains How Atlanteans Survive on Land](https://www.cbr.com/aquaman-atlanteans-breathe-land/)*</sup></sub>

Comment: I realize this is an entirely different question, but... why?

Comment: for the purpose of the film.. if you read the article they explain that this feature is useful for cosmetics and plot purposes @sanpaco

Comment: But there must be an in universe reason. Magic something something evolution?

Comment: probably something like that...

Comment: @sanpaco seems valid enough to be an individual question

Comment: If the only Atlanteans who can breath water and air are highborns, it would suggest that it was a genetic attribute that didn't get passed down to the common folk. After all, the queen was outcast because she mated with someone who wasn't royal lineage Atlantean...

Comment: Atlantis used to be _above_ water, so all Atlanteans once breathed air. Maybe the highborns consciously retained the ability to breath air so they could keep better tabs on the surface world, e.g. by going on land every now and then.

Comment: Aquaman, personally, being half-human, has a built-in excuse.